# How to make React (Router) point to WP backend file

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using Wordpress and the REST API to build an app. Unfortunately, I need to to access a WordPress PHP page at when the user points to /register.

When I point the browser to the /register page, it displays a universal page rendered by react. It's triggered by this:

```
<Route path='*' component = {Single} />
```

How can I make an exception to this rule and retrieve a page from the WordPress backend?

This is my router:

```
<Route path="/">

        <IndexRoute component={Home} /> 
         <Route path='/services' component ={Services} />
        <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
        <Route path='/submit' component = {Submit} />
        <Route path='/myaccount' component = {MyAccount} />
        <Route path='/register' component = {Register} />
        <Route path='/logare' component = {Login} />
       // <Route path='*' component = {Single} />


 </Route>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is `<Route path='*' component = {Single} />` working? Do you want that? Your using an old version of react-router as well, newest version is `react-router-dom v4.2.2`.

Comment: That generic path triggered by " * " is working. I want to access a page create by me using the WordPress backend. That page is available on localhost/request. If I go to localhost/register, than instead of a WordPress page, I get the "Single" Component rendered by React. I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Ah okay, your comment cleared things up for me. You can use the `exact` prop on each `<Route>` to make sure that only exact urls get matched to that component.

```
<Route path="/">

        <IndexRoute component={Home} /> 
         <Route path='/services' component ={Services} />
        <Route path='/blog' component={Blog} />
        <Route path='/submit' component = {Submit} />
        <Route path='/myaccount' component = {MyAccount} />
        <Route exact path='/register' component = {Register} />
        <Route path='/logare' component = {Login} />
        <Route path='*' component = {Single} />


 </Route>
```